# angular service worker installing throwing error : Invalid rule result: Function()

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

angular cli version is 6.0.8 
i m using below command

```
$ ng add @angular/pwa --project flash
```

eg

```
PC@DESKTOP-HLV67E7 MINGW64 /f/avinash-trying/flash (master)
$ ng add @angular/pwa --project flash
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/pwa@0.7.3
updated 1 package in 8.915s
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Invalid rule result: Function().
```

it throwing error    **Invalid rule result: Function().**
thanks in advance